# I am using Bootstrap 4 carousel in a code.Bootstrap 4 carousel not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 carousel in a code. But it is showing all the three images that I am using in individual items in a single item at a time. Here is the code:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
```

Now I want to show single image in a single carousel items. In my code what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your html code is all good.
Please make sure.

1. Bootstrap 4 css and js files is included properply.
2. Jquery is included properly.

**NOTE:** Check console(press **F12** and click console) for errors.
You must find something there.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure Bootstrap 4 **CSS** and **JS** files is linkup in your carousel page 
Specifically, **jquery.min.js** and **popper.min.js** and must **bootstrap.min.js** flies then you paste this code on your carousel page where you want to show

Here you can find more details about carousel [Bootstrap Carousel Details](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/carousel/)

if you setup rightly you can see carousel like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you add some pertinent details from the link and image.